# when i want install any application ot want to open folder as a adminstrator I will got follwing error error incorrect permissions

Tags: policykit

```
error incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)
```

I have tried following command

```
ls -l /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

Expected output is

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 22840 Feb 21 18:28 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

But output come is

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 nayan root 22840 Feb 21 18:28 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

and 2 problem is my in my laptop wifi adpter not showing

```
lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: 60:a5:e2:39:54:81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.14.0-1034-oem firmware=63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:601d194000-601d197fff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by changing ownership of the file back to `root`.

Run

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```